# check if a number is complex number in javascript

Tags: javascript, complex-numbers

In my page, I accept an input from user. I evaluate that expression and print its output.

e.g:

*Input*: `3 + 5`

*Output*: `8`

This work I am doing by *javascript*. The problem I am facing is with complex number/expression.

I am able to do mathematical operations on complex numbers, but for that I need a flag that the given input is a complex number.

The complex number can be in any form.

e.g.

1. *Input*: `(-4)^(1/2) + (-9)^(4/8)`

   *Output*: `5 i`

   the problem here is how to interpret the input as `2i + 3i`.
   I am able to perform the operations if the input is in form `2+3i + 3+4i`.

   I have referred these links:

   http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/complex-number-calculator.html

   https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-9/complex-js-a-complex-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the math.js library to evaluate your expressions?

http://mathjs.org

You can just enter expressions like:

```
math.eval('3 + 5'); // Number 8
math.eval('2i + 3i'); // Complex 5i
math.eval('(-4)^(1/2) + (-9)^(4/8)'); // ~ Complex 5i
```

The last expression has a little round-off error due to JavaScripts floating point numbers.